# trying to attach excel data on the fly to mail

Tags: php, excel, email, yii2, phpexcel

I want to attach an excel file on the fly to the mail.

I am generating an PHPExcel_IOFactory object using following code.

```
$objWriter = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
```

I serialize this object and sent to my mailer and in mailer I use following code to attach it.

```
Yii::$app->mailer->attachContent($excelData, ['fileName' => 'testfile.xlsx', 'contentType' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'])
```

it attaches the data as excel file but when I try to open it. I says "File is corrupted".

Kindly help me out. I do not want to save the excel file before attaching it to the mail.

Comment: You serialize the writer object? Not a good idea. And I don't see you calling `save()` anywhere to actually generate the file

Comment: @Mark I don't want to save the file before uploading it. And yes you are right, serialization is not the good idea here.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to attach the file to the mail.

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
ob_start();
$objWriter->save('php://output');
$excelOutput = ob_get_clean();
```

But the problem with it is , while attaching the content to the mail as attachment it also prompt to save the file.

How can I stop this prompt? and attach the file without prompting file to save.